# How to Validate and Insert changeset in elixir using Mongodb driver?

Tags: mongodb, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am devloping my application using `Phoenix Framework` with database as `Mongodb`
 [i am following this link](https://tomjoro.github.io/2017-02-09-ecto3-mongodb-phoenix/) tutorial to work with mongodb.

My model looks like this

```
defmodule XXXX.Department do
use XXXX.Web, :model

@primary_key {:id, :binary_id, autogenerate: true}
 schema "departments"  do
 field :name, :string
 field :shortDescription, :string
 field :aboutDepartment, :string
end

def changeset(struct, params \\%{}) do
  struct
  |> cast(params, [:name, :shortDescription, :aboutDepartment])
  |> validate_required([:name, :shortDescription])
end
end
```

But when i am trying to insert new document using

```
`{:ok, department} = Mongo.find_one_and_replace(:mongo, "departments", %{},   changeset.changes, [return_document: :after, upsert: :true])`
```

It always updates the first document in collection but does not create new document and validations are also not working.
Then i am trying to insert new document using

```
`Mongo.insert_one!(:mongo, "departments",changeset,changes)`
```

But it does not give a tuple containing like this and validation also not working

```
{:ok, department}
```

what mistake did i make here??How to insert document or get changeset errors??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Mongo Ecto wrapper, but here's an attempt to help:

1) Try using `Mongo.insert_one` without the bang `!` — it is a convention to use the `!` character in functions that would raise an error, instead of returning success/error tuples. Calling `insert` in Ecto returns either `{:ok, result}` or `{:error, changeset}`.

2) Notice in the article that the author is using `Mongo.insert_one(:mongo, "users", user)` — the function takes 3 arguments, not 4.

3) Try using `insert` instead (can't see `insert_one` documented?).

Comment: `insert` is not available,if i try `Mongo.insert_one(:mongo,"departments",changeset)` empty record will inserted into collection  without any validation,and also i don't know why the record gets inserted only if i call `changeset.changes` else it won't get insert into collection